# Proving that a c.d.f. cannot satisfy this property

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Let $F$ denote the CDF of a random variable $X$. Suppose that the support of the distribution of $X$ is $\mathbb{R}$ and $F$ is continuous.

Let $\{\xi_k\}_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty}$ be a doubly infinite sequence of equally spaced point on the real line: 
$$\xi_k-\xi_{k-1}=b>0 \text{ for any } k.$$

Consider the probability of the following countable union of the intervals of length $a$, where $0<a<b$: 
$$ Pr\left( \cup_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} [\xi_k+z, \xi_k + z+a]\right) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} (F(\xi_k + z+a)-F(\xi_k + z)). \qquad \qquad (*)
$$

What I want to show is that it is not possible for this probability (*) to not depend on $z \in \mathbb{R}$. It is enough to consider $z \in (-b,b)$.

I tried to show it by contradiction. It seems to be that if this probability was strictly positive and didn't depend on $z$, then this would imply that $F$ is a non-trivial affine function, and this in its turn would contradict the fact of $F$ being a c.d.f. with the support $\mathbb{R}$.  I am stuck. Maybe there is another way to proceed here. Maybe there are even some general measure properties I could use here.

**EDIT**: after the answer from colt_browning below, I realized another condition needs to be added to the question, which is $b/a$ is not integer.

Comment: Is each choice of $a\in(0,\,b)$ meant to achieve this, or just one?

Comment: @J.G.  Just one choice of $a$. $a$ and $b$ are fixed constants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is not true. Let $\xi_k=2k$, $b=2$, $a=1$, and $F$ grows linearly from $0$ to $1$ on $[0;2]$. Then that probability is always equal to $1/2$.

Edit: ah, yes, support $\mathbb{R}$. Let the partial density function be equal to $2^{-m-2}$ on $(-m;-m+1)$ and $(m+1;m+2)$ for $m=0,1,\ldots$

Comment: The question specifically states that the support of the distribution of  is the whole real line.

Comment: @Neznajka Ah, yes. Edited to satisfy this requirement.

Comment: @colt-browning thanks! In just checked and in my problem $b/a$ is not integer (and  I also have b>2a). i wonder if your example can be extended to a general case.

Comment: @Neznajka In fact, my example works "as is" with any $a$.

Comment: What would make my example invalid is an additional requirement for *PDF* to be continuous. In fact, in that case the statement from your question indeed seems plausible.

Comment: thank you! I will try to add the requirement of the continuity of the p.d.f. and see if i can get a contradiction.